# How to autocmd BufWritePost with CoffeeScript vim up a directory?

Tags: vim, coffeescript

I'm using [this vim plugin for coffeescript](https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script) and I want to keep all my source files in `/src/` even though the compiled files may live elsewhere, like `/` or `/public/js`.

I know I can have vim autosave to the *current* directory using the following (in `.vimrc`):

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.coffee silent CoffeeMake!
```

But I can't figure out how to change that on a per-file basis. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
:autocmd BufWritePost server.coffee silent CoffeeMake! -o ../server.js
```

But nothing happens when I do that (when I save my coffee file): no new files are created, and no errors are thrown.

I'd also love it if I could specify a placeholder for the file name, like this (no clue if this is even close to being right):

```
:autocmd BufWritePost @%.coffee silent CoffeeMake! -o ../@%.js
```

Can anyone help me make this work the way I want?

---

EDIT: Coffee expects the `-o` param to just be the directory (not the file), so the final solution should be something like

```
:autocmd BufWritePost *.coffee silent execute 'CoffeeMake! -o '.expand('<afile>:p:h').'/../'
```

... if you wanted it in the root of your web app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following command.

```
:autocmd BufWritePost *.coffee
\   silent execute 'CoffeeMake! -o ' .
\   expand('<afile>:p:h') . '/../' . expand('<afile>:t:r') . 'js'
```

The name of the file that matched an auto-command can be determined
using the `<afile>` cmdline-special variable. To extract its value in
an expression, use the `expand()` function. Additional modifiers allow
to extract the full path or remove the file extension (see `:help expand()`).

Answer (score 1):

If you have app with file structure like this (or any other structure with different directory name ):

```
app -- 
      coffee --
                module1 -- 
                           ..files
                module2 --
                           ..files
      js --
                module1 -- 
                           ..files
                module2 --
                           ..files
```

you might want to consider this as well:

```
autocmd BufWritePost,FileWritePost *.coffee silent execute 'CoffeeMake! -o '.expand('%:p:h:s?coffee?js?')
```

the last bit `:s?coffee?js?` replaces first occurance of `coffee` with `js` in your save path

more info: `:help filename-modifiers`